# Sequelize hasMany association not working properly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, belongs-to

Something is wrong with my code and I can't find where it is.
I'm using Sequelize on my node server.
It seems like i can't make belongsTo association work.

Here is the error I catch from the promise:

> [TypeError: Property 'setDetails' of object [object
>   SequelizeInstance:car] is not a function]

Actually what it does is INSERT the detail data but without the car_id and it does not INSERT data in car table.

And here is what I have:

models/detail.js file:

```
var Detail = pg.sequelize.define('details', {
        color: {
            type: pg.Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: true
    }
);

module.exports = Detail;
```

models/car.js

```
var Detail  = require('../models/detail');
var Car = pg.sequelize.define('cars', {
        id: {
            type: pg.Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: {
            type: pg.Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        underscored: true
    }
);
var c = Detail.belongsTo(Car, {
    as: 'detail',
    foreignKey: 'car_id',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
Car.c = c;
module.exports = Car;
```

router/car.js

```
var Car  = require('../models/car');
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

    var createData = {
        title: req.body.title,
        detail: {
            color: req.body.color
        }
    };

    Car.create(createData, { include: [ Car.c ] })
        .then(function(result) {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

});

module.exports = router;
```

I have been able to make an hasMany association but not this one.

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to have an answer from mickhansen on IRC about this.

> mickhansen: "you need the relationship for the side you query from, and since
>   you're creating from the Car side, you need the Car -> Detail
>   relation."

It make sense. There is an exemple here :
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#foreign-keys_1

Hope this helps.